# Velocity test-package with html-reporter won't show anything

Tags: meteor, jasmine, meteor-velocity, meteor-packages

My app is structured in packages, each with their corresponding test suites.
I've added `sanjo:jasmine` as my testing engine and `velocity:html-reporter`, but when I run the following command I receive no output and the browser won't connect to the server in port 3000,

```
$ velocity test-package hogares --driver-package velocity:html-reporter@0.9.0
```

This is the test part of my **package.js**

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.use('sanjo:jasmine@0.20.2');
  api.use('hogares');
  api.addFiles('tests/server/hogares.specs.js', 'server');
  api.addFiles('tests/client/hogares.specs.js', 'client');
});
```

Any idea? Thanks!